# How can I redirect multiple devise model to multiple specific urls?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I got three independent devise models, ergo I got three different sign_in screen. And all three have got a dashboard:

```
devise_for :md1
devise_for :md2
devise_for :md3

match 'md1/dashboard' => 'md1#dashboard', :via => :get
match 'md2/dashboard' => 'md2#dashboard', :via => :get
match 'md3/dashboard' => 'md3#dashboard', :via => :get
```

I want when there is a mdX succesfully sign in, it will redirect to mdX#dashboard, and if it is possible by GET. I tried:

```
devise_scope :md1 do
  root :to => 'md1#dashboard'
end
devise_scope :md2 do
  root :to => 'md2#dashboard'
end
devise_scope :md3 do
  root :to => 'md3#dashboard'
end
```

Then when I succesfully sign in with md1 I got redirected to md1 dashboard, but when I succesfully sign in with md2 I got redirected to md1's sign_in screen.
Then I tried:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for resource
  dashboard_path resource
end
```

But there isn't such method. Is there an easy way to do this or it has to be with the `if` statements for each model?

### UPDATE

Some routes to make a better understanding and more information to get a better solution

```
md1_dashboard GET    /md1/dashboard(.:format)        md1#dashboard
md2_dashboard GET    /md2/dashboard(.:format)        md2#dashboard
md3_dashboard GET    /md3/dashboard(.:format)        md3#dashboard
```

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Good question. I've solved this problem with a clunky if elsif block. If there's a better way I'd like to know about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you are writing this:

```
devise_scope :md1 do
  root :to => 'md1#dashboard'
end
devise_scope :md2 do
  root :to => 'md2#dashboard'
end
devise_scope :md3 do
  root :to => 'md3#dashboard'
end
```

You are defining three root routes, with the same name. Since they conflict, only the first will be used. That's why only md1 worked. You probably meant to write this:

```
scope :md1 do
  root :to => 'md1#dashboard'
end
scope :md2 do
  root :to => 'md2#dashboard'
end
scope :md3 do
  root :to => 'md3#dashboard'
end
```

On this case, you will define three different root routes, at three different scopes (check `rake routes` again). Note `scope` is a router method that scopes your routes, `devise_scope` does not scope any route, it simply tells which devise scope you want to use, which you don't need to tell unless Devise explicitly asks you so (you will know when it does).

After this change, everything should work as expected. Note that Devise by default uses `#{scope}_root_path` to redirect after successful sign in, that's why the code above works (check `rake routes` and you will see you `md1_root`, `md2_root`, etc are now defined).

Comment: Thank you for the answer and I'm glad that YOU answered. I appreciate your work, since Oxente Rails :)